# Widget for listview

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm not sure if this is possible, but here is the brief:
I have an app that load a listview (list of magnetic Doors) based on the username and password (saved in preferences). if user press any door from the list,  specific command will be sent to the server to momentarily unlock the selected door. till now, everything is working perfectly. 
now, the whole purpose of this app is to provide something very quick to unlock a door. I want to give an option to the user to place a shortcut widget for the frequently used doors, to directly unlock, instead of entering the app, load the doors, and then press on the door to unlock.
all direct and indirect helps are welcome.

Comment: Yes you can add a widget to your app which the user can place on one of its home screens. At selecting an item in the listview you could configure your widget.

Comment: Dit you search/google for something like 'android widget tutorial'?

Comment: I'm not talking about normal widget here. I'm talking about using my application to create shortcut in run-time. something similar to contacts in android, you can open any contact, and place shortcut on home screen.

Comment: Then please adapt the subject of this post.